# Trying to develop stories in wit.ai that differ between how vs why

Tags: wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building out my wit.ai app to handle a variety of questions from a user. Everything is going fine but my wit.ai is starting to get confused around 'how' vs 'why' questions. I'm looking for the best way to structure these with entities/roles/values.

Eg.
Story 1: Why do I need to change my password?
Story 2: How do I change my password?
Story 3: Where do I change my password?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use different entity for 'What','Why','How' etc. Like for 'What' you can use something like 'query_what', for 'Why' use 'query_why'.

You can have a look in this app: https://wit.ai/saimoom.akash/Playground/

Comment: Nice, I also tried creating intent subroles for Who, What, Where, Why, How which helped immensely and kept from having create a lot of custom entities.

Eg. 'intent:how' = How